# Should new instance of Java Collection extension (eg. List) implementation be returned as the return value instead of existing one?

Tags: java, collections

I've been taught that if there is some method which return type is java.util.Collection extension implementation (for this example lets assume it's List interface implemented by ArrayList) I should return its new instance. To be precise let me put here an example:

```
public List<Something> getListOfSomething() {
    List<Something> somethingsList = methodCall(); //some method execution which returns list of something
    //some code

    return new ArrayList<>(somethingList); //returning list implementation
}
```

If you look at my snippet you'll see constructor call `return new ArrayList<>(somethingList)`.

#### My questions are:

Is this correct approach?

If yes (or no) - why?

If it depends - depends on what?

---

I've been looking for an answer through the Stack, but couldn't even find similar question.

Answer (score 0):

It is safe, as it cannot modify the originally returned list.
However that normally is the resposibility of the called method itself.
You would not like having copies of copies, or needlessly copy.

Under some circumstances you could do:

```
return Collections.unmodifiableList(somethingList);
```

The returned list is no longer modifiable, but that might not suit the caller.

I would leave the responsibility to the methodCall to not expose internal data.
If it is a private method, and yours is a public one, then it might be your responsibility. Check whether the data stems from a field, as then you risk exposing internal data to the exterior world.

And finally you could return a **Stream** which is best.

```
public Stream<Something> getStreamOfSomething() {
    List<Something> somethingsList = methodCall();
    ...
    return somethingList.stream();
}
```

A Stream gives no access to the List object whether it exposes an internal field to the outside world or not. It everytime gives a new stream/iteration through the list, and one could turn it in a list, or whatever.

Also if you need to do something with the elements of the original list, it is likely you would call .stream() on the list anyway. Otherwise:

```
List<Something> somethingsList = obj.getStreamOfSomething().collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: I like your answer but could you please explain why returning Stream is the best approach?

Comment: @OscarKuźniar okay, added the rationale, I should have taken the time to explain the alternative to returning a List.